# Jenkins console not outputting some "special" characters like ✗, and ✓

Tags: jenkins, k6

When running a load test using k6, the output is hard to read because many characters are not output correctly.

Specifically it's "special" characters like ✗, and ✓

The output looks like this:

[image]

The output is in the "Console" section viewed in a Chrome browser.

The same issue exists in the Blue Ocean console in the browser.

How can I configure Jenkins to display these properly?

Answer (score 0):

Add option `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` when starting the Java process for the remote node.